# How can I display on the UI sanitized Emojis?

Tags: c#, .net, emoji

I am trying to sanitize against user input by calling `Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(input)`.

This converts my Emoji ‍♂️ to something like `\U0001f9da&#55356;`
And while showing back on UI, it is displaying the above text instead of Emoji.
If I don't use sanitizer then it is displaying Emoji on UI.

Can anyone help me in retaining Emoji's using `GetSafeHtmlFragment` function in C#.

Comment: Which C# framework are you using? i.e. ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms, etc.?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.6.1 class library, Its WebAPI and i am posting data from HTML page.